# Can't deserialize JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I receive the following JSON string from a 3rd party:

```
{
    "Ch": [{
        "i": 100,
        "m": "Time",
        "u": "(sec)",
        "d": 0,
        "z": 0.345313,
        "yi": "0.000000",
        "ya": "6.906250",
        "a": 0,
        "s": 1664,
        "data": "RN]]>"
    }, {
        "i": 101,
        "m": "Stress",
        "u": "(kPa)",
        "d": 0,
        "z": 60,
        "yi": "0.000000",
        "ya": "1200.000000",
        "a": 0
    }, {
        "i": 102,
        "m": "Strain",
        "u": "(micro e)",
        "d": 0,
        "z": 8,
        "yi": "200.000000",
        "ya": "360.000000",
        "a": 0
    }, {
        "i": 103,
        "m": "Stress",
        "u": 360,
        "d": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "yi": "0.000000",
        "ya": "0.000000",
        "a": 0,
        "s": 1664,
        "data": "QVORR`Pb_UQRR</code>OObTNRRUTaWRVRRSaPQPdRRaPNSORRR]]>"
    }, {
        "i": 104,
        "m": "Strain",
        "u": 360,
        "d": 0,
        "z": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "yi": "0.000000",
        "ya": "0.000000",
        "a": 1,
        "s": 1664,
        "data": "SVdRQSP_VWQRQa]]>"
    }]
}
```

I use the following classes:

```
public class testCh
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public string m { get; set; }
    public object u { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
    public string yi { get; set; }
    public string ya { get; set; }
    public int a { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int s { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string data { get; set; }

}

public class testRootObject
{
    public List<testCh> tCh { get; set; }
}
```

And finally I try this in my main class:

```
var response1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testRootObject>(content1);

foreach (testCh tc in response1.tCh)
{
    string name = tc.m;
}
```

I do get an empty testRootObject[]

I've tried ignoring "a" and "data" in my testCH class:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public int s { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public string data { get; set; }
```

and it didn't work.

I'm not sure why I can't deserialize it. It must be something silly but after trying for a couple days I can't see it.

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Please, format your JSON. It is completely unreadable

Comment: Try renaming the `tCh` property of the `testRootObject` class to `Ch`.

Comment: try a same name for the object... in the c# class and the json. because it looks out for a matching name.

Comment: @JasonBoyd It worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this out and confirmed. The only error you got here is that the name of the list object. It should be `Ch` as in your json string.

```
public class testRootObject
{
    public List<testCh> Ch { get; set; }
}
```

If it is a must that that properties name should be `tCh` than you can do the following:

```
public class testRootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Ch")]
    public List<testCh> tCh { get; set; }
}
```